# Как открыть порт для apache в termux

Tags: apache, apache2, port, site, termux

Я хочу сделать хост на телефоне, но не знаю как открыть порт для apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае, если у вас есть статический ip адрес, то открывать порт для apache впринципе не должно являться необходимостью (он должен работать из коробки), если же он есть, но apache не работает, то можете почитать статью на медиуме https://medium.com/@HuffyPiet/how-i-set-up-apache2-web-server-with-termux-on-android-2d7e31aac63e
Т.к в рамках одного ответа невозможно описать все, что нужно сделать, чтобы настроить апач в термуксе. Если же у вас динамический ip, то подключиться к вашему apache серверу вы можете только из одной сети с этим сервером(wifi, localhost все дела).